# Find last row with two conditions on columns

Tags: excel, vba, loops, find, row

I am looking for the last row of my Excel dataset which fits the following two conditions:
Myrow's Column("E") = some_value
Myrow's Column("K") is Not empty

If column("K") is empty then look for the **previous** row fullfilling the conditions above.

I want to continue looping over the column("E") as long as The corresponding column("K") is empty.

I tried the following:

```
With worksheets("myworksheet"):
Set my_first_cell = Range(“E:E”).Find(What:="some_value", lookin:xlValues, 
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
Set my_second_cell = my_first_cell.Offset(0,6)
If Not my_second_cell Is Nothing Then:
    myrow=my_second_cell.Row
Do
Set my_first_cell= .FindPrevious(my_first_cell)
Loop While my_second_cell Is Nothing
End If
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it out, I use the last row in column K to start

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, LstRw As Long
    Dim x
    Dim myRow As String
    Set sh = Worksheets("myworksheet")

    With sh

        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row

        For x = LstRw To 2 Step -1

            If .Cells(x, "K") <> "" And .Cells(x, "E") = "some_value" Then
                myRow = x
                Exit For
            End If



        Next

    End With

    MsgBox myRow
End Sub
```